# What do these two sentences mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The first sentence is this: That was how it was with her. What does that mean **"That was how it was..."**?
The second sentence is this: What did I even do?. What does that mean **"I even do..."**?

I read these sentences in a book and I didn't quite understand it. Looks like the first one's saying something went on.

Answer (score 1):

"That was how it was with her" has to do with her personality, how she reacts in a particular situation and I suspect that situation occurred shortly before.

"What did I even do" means you did something that she is angry or sad about, but you do not understand why or you don't think what you did is bad.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand these sentences.